# DB2 SQL: altering join query to provide required result

Tags: sql, db2

Main `Table_1`:

```
ID    ROLE              CODE
______________________________
1     DIRECTOR          CD1
1     PRODUCER          CD2 
1     ACTOR             CD10
2     PRODUCER          CD5
2     ACTOR             CD11
2     DIRECTOR          CD8
2     SPOT_BOY          CD97
3     ACTOR             CD12
3     DIRECTOR          CD41
______________________________
```

Reference `Table_2`:

```
COL_NAME     REF_VALUE
____________________________
DIRECTOR     DIR
PRODUCER     PROD
ACTOR        ACT
SPOT_BOY     SPB
____________________________
```

`ROLE` column of `Table_1` joins with `COL_NAME` column of `Table_2`

Reference `Table_3`:

```
CODE      NAME
_________________________
CD1       ONE
CD2       TWO
CD5       FIVE
CD10      TEN
CD11      ELEVEN
CD12      TWELVE
CD97      NINETY_SEVEN
CD8       EIGHT
CD41      FORTY_ONE
_________________________
```

`CODE` column of `Table_1` joins with `CODE` column of `Table_3`

Query:

```
select 
   a.id, a.role, b.ref_value, c.code, c.name  
from 
   table_1 a, table_2 b, table_3 c
where 
   a.id = 1 
   and a.role = b.col_name 
   and a.code = c.code
```

results in:

```
ID    ROLE        REF_VALUE   CODE     NAME 
___________________________________________
 1    DIRECTOR    DIR         CD1      ONE
 1    PRODUCER    PROD        CD2      TWO
 1    ACTOR       ACT         CD10     TEN
___________________________________________
```

Without modifying any of the three tables, I want to modify above query such that: Whenever the `ROLE` in `Table_1` is `PRODUCER` (or the `REF_VALUE` in `Table_2` is `PROD`), the corresponding `CODE` from `Table_1` (or `CODE` from `Table_3`) and `NAME` from `Table_3` should be taken as that of `ROLE` `DIRECTOR` for that `ID`.

i.e. The modified query for `ID` 1 should result in:

```
ID    ROLE        REF_VALUE   CODE     NAME 
___________________________________________
 1    DIRECTOR    DIR         CD1      ONE
 1    PRODUCER    PROD        CD1      ONE
 1    ACTOR       ACT         CD10     TEN
___________________________________________
```

The modified query for `ID` 2 should result in:

```
ID    ROLE        REF_VALUE   CODE     NAME 
_____________________________________________________
 2    PRODUCER    PROD        CD8      EIGHT
 2    ACTOR       ACT         CD11     ELEVEN
 2    DIRECTOR    DIR         CD8      EIGHT
 2    SPOT_BOY    SPB         CD97     NINETY_SEVEN
_____________________________________________________
```

In other words, with above given table structure (and no option to modify the structure or data in the tables), I want a query in which given any `ID`, the `CODE` and `NAME` values for roles `PROD` and `DIR` should be the values corresponding to role `DIR` for that `ID`.

I am using DB2 database.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: 1) It feels like `Table_1.role` values should be switched with `Table_2.col_name` values. 2) Is this something that should be permanently switched (ie, update the database)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: No.. I am not allowed to update the database... checking your solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple with an additional join.  It's easiest to wrap this up in a subquery or CTE, though:

```
WITH PrdDir AS (SELECT Df.id, Df.role, COALESCE(Ot.code, Df.code) AS code
                FROM Table_1 Df
                LEFT JOIN Table_1 Ot
                       ON Ot. id = Df.id
                          AND Df.role = 'PRODUCER'
                          AND Ot.role = 'DIRECTOR')

SELECT PrdDir.id, PrdDir.role, Table_2.ref_value, Table_3.code, Table_3.name 
FROM PrdDir
JOIN Table_2
  ON Table_2.col_name = PrdDir.role
JOIN Table_3
  ON Table_3.code = PrdDir.code
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/646c4/2/0)</kbd>

Please don't use the implicit-join syntax (the comma-separated `FROM` clause) - for one thing, you can't do `LEFT JOIN`s with it in DB2 - in this query, if there is no director, at least the producer will still be returned.  For another it's all too easy to forget a condition, and get a Cartesian product by accident.